# Spring Webjars locator and context-path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot application with enabled Spring Security configured like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/webjars/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Everything works fine until I change context-path. For example, if I set the it like this:

```
server:
   context-path: /myapp
```

I cant access my webjars, css... They are still looked at: http://localhost:8080/webjars/...

How can I configure Spring Webjars so that it works regardless of context-path?

Comment: what is the configuration of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter ?

Comment: Configuration looks like this:
     registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem.

What I forget to do is request Thymeleaf engine to process relative paths of my CSS and js files. So, basically I changed this in my template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
```